# Is it possible to split EmberJS' vendor file into multiple files?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

EmberJS, via the ember-cli project, compiles both a `vendor.js` file and an `application-name.js` file. I have noticed that `vendor.js` can grow to be quite large. Is it possible to split `vendor.js` across multiple files—either as `vendor.1.js` ... `vendor.n.js` or in a more contextual ways like `these-components.js` and `those-components.js`?

If it isn't possible, or not reasonably feasible to do the above, how does one prevent the `vendor.js` file from bloating to unreasonable sizes?

Right now it seems like any moderately complex EmberJS application will be an unmanageable nightmare from a dependency perspective, especially for mobile browsers.

Comment: Not easily, and they would all have to be loaded eventually anyway.

Comment: So is the only solution then having a single, potentially massive, `vendor.js` file? For a reasonably complex project how does one maintain a sensibly sized vendor file?

Comment: Unless you want to do some ugly hacks (which others before you have done), you're going to have to wait for some advances in technology involving smart packing/dynamic loading/HTTP2 etc. Think Ember 3. Even then, there is the underlying problem that Ember is huge by virtue of its very kitchen-sink philosophy. The typical response to such problems is that "we have some super-cool ideas which are going to be implemented real soon". Meanwhile, you could split out some 3rd-party modules and load them dynamically, although that will be of only marginal help.

Comment: Don't forget that the development environment `vendor.js` is quite different in size from the production one.Ember will have an app size comparable to similar applications developed with other tech.

Comment: @locks Fair, but when did we become OK with web assets (even gzipped) at even 1.5 MB or more... it just feels like bloat. Maybe my age is beginning to show... :D Thanks to everyone for their comments on this!

Comment: That's a discussion for another day and another place ;p Join us on Slack.

Comment: enable gzip for your assets on server - in our case it compress files more that in 10